# Alphabetize list by using last 3 characters with C#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, alphabetical

I have a list of strings like this:

1. 123.45 ABC
2. 678.90 DEF
3. 543.21 FED

I want to sort the list alphabetically using the last 3 characters of each list element.

EDIT: Using C#, how do I alphabetize this list by using the last 3 characters of each element?

Comment: You need to create a [custom comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/comparisons-and-sorts-within-collections) or [C# – Custom method of sorting strings](http://csharp.academy/custom-method-of-sorting-strings/)

Comment: `OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.Length - 3)` for the last 3 `OrderBy(x => x.Substring(N))` for starting at the Nth character

Comment: @juharr, this sorts the list numerically unfortunately

Comment: @paulsm4 I will give this a go, thank you I will let you know if this works

Comment: Those appear to already be sorted alphabetically by the last three characters. What is the expected output?? Also, it would be more useful if you included an actual code sample, like `var items = new List<string> {"543.21 FED", "123.45 ABC", "678.90 DEF"};`, so we're all using the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would first do is to ensure that I filter out all strings that have less than 3 characters. Then I would order them as:

```
var items = new List<string> { "13 zzz", "12 yyy", "11 zzz" };

items = items.Where(i => i.Length > 2)
             .OrderBy(i => i.Substring(i.Length - 3))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: You are correct. Let me fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

To order by the last three characters, you can just take the `Substring` starting at `Length - 3` and use that in the `OrderBy` method (note that we should first check that `item.Length > 2` so that `Substring` doesn't throw an execption):

```
var items = new List<string> {"543.21 FED", "123.45 ABC", "678.90 DEF"};

items = items
    .OrderBy(item => item?.Length > 3 ? item.Substring(item.Length - 3) : item)
    .ToList();

// result: {"123.45 ABC", "678.90 DEF", "543.21 FED"}
```

---

Alternatively, you can write a custom comparer for the strings and then pass that to the `Sort` method. We can include a constructor for our comparer that takes in an `int` that specifies how many characters we want to count from the end of the string to make it more flexible (like if you want to use the last `5` characters, or the last `2`, etc.).

```
public class OrderByLastNChars : Comparer<string>
{
    public int N { get; set; }

    public OrderByLastNChars(int n)
    {
        N = n;
    }

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;
        var first = x.Length > N ? x.Substring(x.Length - N) : x;
        var second = y.Length > N ? y.Substring(x.Length - N) : y;
        return first.CompareTo(second);
    }
}
```

Then this can be used like:

```
items.Sort(new OrderByLastNChars(3));
```

Comment: For some reason this still only sorted the list by the numbers. @Efthymios Kalyviotis's answer worked. Thank you very much though!

Comment: Shouldn't your `item?.Length` also account for the null case by coalescing to a value that would make the comparison false?  I.E. `item => (item?.Length ?? 0) > 2 ? item.Substring(item.Length - 3) : item`  Or does it actually accept a nullable value in a comparison like SQL would?

Comment: @RobParker Since `null > 2 == false`, there's no need for that (the `int` is implicitly converted to a `Nullable<int>` by the compiler for the comparison).

Comment: @Brydon our answers are identical except his *removes* any strings that have a length of 3 or less. Was that part of the requirement?

Comment: @RufusL it wasn't a requirement yet his worked.. It doesn't matter if it removes strings with a length of < 3 because the strings are randomly generated and will always have a length of 3

Comment: @Brydon Interesting. Can you provide an example of strings that work with his but not mine? I'm really curious now!